# Showing formatted digits in textField iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am taking data from XMl file, the distance in xml is like

```
<distance>13.472987570222 km</distance>
```

Now i want to show just two digits after . operator. i.e i want to show in textField like 13.47 km. i have saved this distance digits in NSString *distance;

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use very powerful class `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"##0.## km"];
[numberFormatter setNegativeFormat:@"##0.## km"];
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[distance doubleValue]];
NSString *formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:number];
```

For more info read [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
float theDistance = [distance floatValue];
NSString *roundedDistance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",theDistance];
```

That will round to 2dp. :)

Comment: This is not good decision because if the number will be, for example, int == `100001` then you will display `100001.00`

Comment: Fair enough - personally I always use this if I'm rounding to decimal places - the consistency looks good in formatting IMO. :)

Comment: i also used it but thing is it is showing 0.00 coz distance consist km as well i think

Comment: Ah, have a look at NSString's `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` method then. :) Should be pretty easy to remove the `km`.

Answer (score 0):

Strikes me you should really be converting the xml string into a float or some other such appropriate type and then using a format specifier when displaying the value.